# Dynamically set disabled to textarea in angular reactiveform

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

i want to make disable forms dynamically based on user role, i have set my textarea like this

```
<textarea [attr.disabled]="access == 'read'" formControlName="answer"name="" nbInput fullWidthplaceholder="Masukkan jawaban disini"></textarea>
```

in other input i use `[disabled]="access == 'read'"` idk that doesn't work with textarea,and only works with att.disabled, but the problem is i got textarea but disabled even if the `access` is not `read` and the other input is editable.

[image]

so i check developer tools, the `disabled` textarea has been set to false so it should be not disable but why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: Since you are using reactive form you can disable any form control using reactive form i.e `textAreaName: [{value: 'someValue', disabled:true}]`

Comment: I've made a Stackblitz, and it's working with `[disabled]` insteand of `[att.disabled]`

Comment: can i see your working code?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-i6pksk?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: youre using template driven form not reactive forms, am i correct?

Comment: What is `access` ? With ReactiveForm, you can manage the `disabled` from your .ts. So when the access value change (.valueChanges()), set the disabled property to true or false

Comment: actually it's just permission whether it's read only or admin

Comment: i have set `answer: new FormControl([{value: [[]], disabled:true}], Validators.required)` but nothing happen so i just hardcode it on my html

Comment: works fine for me too with [disabled]="access === 'read'" https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-v1deta?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @naoval could you create stackblitz with the code you have it will be easy to debug your code rather adding ours.

Comment: wait, iactually have reproduce this apps

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uahtjx here i create simple version, not exactly the same but does the same structure

Comment: any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this ?

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.form = fb.group({
    ...
    answer: [{ value: '', disabled: this.access === 'read' ? true : false }]
  });
```

Comment: i have set it but i got an error, the problem is in my checkbox is giving me `Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined` so i change value from `''` to `[[]]` but still giving me that error

Answer (score 2):

Try making it ternary, like `[attr.disabled]="(access == 'read')? true : null"`
This worked for me.

[Source](https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/11160434.html)

Comment: thanks mate, but actually first answer is what i need, but thanks again

Comment: great answerer.